# Friedman test medians

Tags: spss, median

I am trying to run a Friedman test as a non-parametric alternative to repeated measure ANOVA. I calculated the medians for each group just to have a look at and then ran a Friedman test. When the Friedman test gave the 50th percentile (median) it was different to the median values I had previously found. I think this is because I have missing values in my data and during the Friedman test if there is a missing value it gets rid of the rest of the values for that individual in the other groups as well. Whereas, the standard median calculation does not do this. Is there any way around this so that the Friedman test does not remove the values for each individual in every group when one group has a missing value? I hope this makes sense.

See image of the data:
[image]
So for example, in the first row all of the values are not being included in the August, Sep, Oct or Nov medians just because there is a missing value in the Oct column.

Answer (score 0):

The FRIEDMAN test as it is requires complete cases. An alternative has been proposed but is not implemented in SPSS Statistics. See [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2761045/) for more details.